# In what order should I watch the original Planet of the Apes film series?

Tags: suggested-order, planet-of-the-apes

Given that the [original Planet of the Apes film series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_of_the_Apes) features time travel both ways and some later films tie back to the first film in the series, in what order should I watch the films?

Is it better to watch the films in release order or chronological order?

I have not seen all of the original film series, but do know the general premise.

Comment: In my opinion, the answer to this question should always be "the order in which they were made."

Comment: in this particular case, "The order in which they were made, and only the first two."   But yeah, there's no way to answer that unless you're specifically asking for something like "If I wanted to watch the Ape movies in chronological order..."

Comment: Personally, I don't understand the desire to watch a franchise in *anything other than* the order in which they were first released.  I mean, maybe if you've seen them a hundred times before and you feel like experimenting, sure.  But first time?  Just watch them in order already!

Comment: The old films aren't in the least bit important to the new films. Just watch them in filmed order if you fancy more ape fun

Comment: Unless you are asking 'what would be a chronological order' of viewing the films vs production order, this is clearly an opinion based quesiton

Comment: I'd still say the use of the word 'better' by definition implies an opinion. Not sure how to get around what you are really asking vs what would be on topic for the site...in my opinion :)

Comment: I can't find an existing question asking simply 'what is the chronological viewing order of the apes movie' - maybe the question just needs to be asked like that instead of the subjective request to determine which order is better?

Comment: My recommended order is:  1. Planet of the Apes (1968).

Comment: Relevant: [In what order should I watch The planet of the Apes franchise? - Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50615/in-what-order-should-i-watch-the-planet-of-the-apes-franchise)

Comment: @NKCampbell If you think this is an opinion based question then are these also opinion based questions? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/in-what-order-should-i-watch-the-various-stargate-tv-series and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/in-what-order-should-the-star-wars-movies-be-watched and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37689/in-which-order-should-i-start-watching-star-trek and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10009/what-order-should-the-babylon-5-movies-and-series-be-watched-in

Comment: the first one clearly states it is looking for objective facts, and the others yeah, they are. I've been noodling over how to bring this up in meta but just haven't had the time or inclination

Comment: @NKCampbell I guess start VTC, because without Word of God, every `suggested-order` question could be called opinion.

Comment: @NKCampbell Quesions about reading-order have come up in Meta a couple of times. Here's a link to one answer. https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11069/63201

Comment: Fair enough - good explanation in that meta - I've retracted my close vote :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(note - this answer ignores the Tim Burton re-make)

There are four ways of viewing the PotA series (including the modern re-tellings). Each one will, essentially, track the story of a character or a theme:

**Option 1: Production order** [the story of Cornelius]

**Option 2: Chronological-Retro** [the story of the planet]

**Option 3: Semi-Chronological-Limited** [the story of Taylor]

**Option 4: Chronological-Modern** [the story of Caesar]

**Option 5: Comprehensive-Destiny** [you can't escape the ape] (kind of a joke answer ;)

---

**The Story of Cornelius:**

Introduces Cornelius, Zira, and his family and follows their journey through space/time in a linear / timey-wimey fashion

- Planet of the Apes
- Beneath the Planet of the Apes
- Escape from Planet of the Apes
- Conquest of the Planet of the Apes
- Battle for the Planet of the Apes

---

**Chronological-Retro**

The original story of the planet in as linear a fashion as possible:

- Escape from the Planet of the Apes
- Conquest of the Planet of the Apes
- Battle for the Planet of the Apes
- Planet of the Apes
- Beneath the Planet of the Apes

---

**Semi-Chronological-Limited**:

The story of Taylor - with no history on the origin of the planet:

- Planet of the Apes
- Beneath the Planet of the Apes

---

**Chronological-Modern**

Revised history of the story of Caesar [remains to be seen if current series will directly link to the original PotA but, this list assumes that is the intention given WftPotA film]:

- Rise of the Planet of the Apes
- Dawn of the Planet of the Apes
- War for the Planet of the Apes
- The Planet of the Apes
- Beneath the Planet of the Apes
- [at this point - uncertainty if the 'Cornelius' arc should be employed]

---

** Comprehensive-Destiny **

In which retro and modern are combined to produce a time loop demonstrating that the planet was meant / doomed no matter what timeline shenanigans happen

Notes on Production order:

1) The primary reveal at the end of the original Planet of the Apes film is one of the most iconic and referenced endings in science fiction. To watch the films 'out of order' in relation to production is to remove the underlying mystery of the original. That being said, this is really only a consideration for somebody entirely unfamiliar with the work. Dramatic irony, of course, is always at play but there is something to be said for that first time 'ah!' moment

*note on the answer - this could be more detailed with plot points probably (but would require spoiler tags) - may do so as I have time, or if it is used as a starting point, happy to convert to Community*

Comment: Whoa! well done, so much detail but I would suggest your Cornelius choice as the most complete!!

Comment: +1 This is a better answer than the one in the Movies & TV forum. https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50615/in-what-order-should-i-watch-the-planet-of-the-apes-franchise

Comment: wow - thanks @RichS!